# Save matrix in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I'm kindly new on C#.

I build a matrix as a multidimensional array. The data are made by single char like

```
a | g | f | r | o
t | * | h | s | u
y | j | f | . | k
```

So I used

```
char[,] matrix= new char[5, 3];
```

In this way I have a matrix with 5 colmuns and 3 row.
Now I want to collect different matrix, and save the in an new array or in another kind of structure...

In pseudocode I want to do:

```
arrayOfMatrix.AddNewItem(matrix);
```

to collect all the matrixs in one array (or lists?). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `List<char[,]> arrayOfMatrix = new List<char[,]>()`, then `arrayOfMatrix.Add(matrix)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `List<T>`!

`List<T>` is a collection type that acts like an array but it does not have a fixed length so you can add items dynamically to it.

Let's see this in action!

First, create a list of character matrices:

```
var list = new List<char[,]>();
```

Then, create a character matrix and add it to the list:

```
char[,] m1 = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}};
list.Add(m1);
```

You can access the list by calling its indexer:

```
Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
```

There are a lot of cool methods and properties in `List` that allows you to manipulate it however you want:

- `Count`
- `Contains`
- `Clear`
- `Find`
- `IndexOf`
- `Insert`
- `Remove`
- `Reverse`
- `Sort`

Go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx for more info.

Comment: Thanks very useful. I accept your answer because is more complete!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generic [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) of multidimensional arrays like this:

```
List<char[,]> arrayOfMatrix = new List<char[,]>();
arrayOfMatrix.Add(matrix1);
arrayOfMatrix.Add(matrix2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with `char` elements, it will be simpler for you to represent row of `char`s as a `string`. So, your matrix becomes an array of strings or list of strings.

```
List<string> matrix = new List<string>()
{
   "agfro",
   "t*hsu",
   "yjf.k"
}
```

Declare:

```
List<List<string>> matrix_list = new List<List<string>>() { matrix };
```

Then keep adding your new matrices into matrix_list as needed. Your access to elements is going to be `matrix_list[list_ix][row_ix][column_ix]` where ix is short for index.

Now, what you get is really the jagged arrays, so it is up to your code to enforce matrix widths and lengths.